# Drag and drop Table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I've found a few plugins that does this, but they either have more than what I want which gets in the way and none of them do exactly what I need. Some I simply can't get to work with firebug showing syntax errors in the style sheets even though it seems perfectly fine.

I want something very simple in terms of visuals. Basically I want this:
http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/groupingsorting/grouping.aspx

If you look at the link then you will see that you can re-order the columns by dragging the headers, but you can also drag the headers out to where it says "Drag a column header here to group by that column"

I just want a plain way to do this in javascript/jquery with some callback so I can store the column order in an array after you change the order. The data changes I can handle, it's the dragging of the columns and then changing the order or removing the column and adding it to the Group space above that I have issues with.

We actually do you devexpress controls, but for what we're doing it's to slow with all the callbacks their grid needs to do when you do anything on the thing. So we're in the process of creating our own ajax grid that does what we want and how we want it with only what we need.

I hope this makes sense and that someone can help.

Comment: Do you have an example of some code you have tried?

Comment: Honestly, I've only tried the plugins like dragtable although I can't get the latest version of dragtable to work. That said, it doesn't do everything I need anyway. I'm not even sure where to start with this so I don't really have code to post. I'm far from being an jquery/javscript expert which is why I'm hoping someone might have done something like this in a simple form that could give advice on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently looked at implementing something similar, so while I can't post a code example, I'd recommend looking at [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to let you drag the columns to where you want them.

Make the table column order configurable through javascript first. Then make the column headings draggable and based on the new position redraw the table based on the new column layout.

This approach should be faster as you can optimise for your use cases.